# Add space to :after with float:right

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
.my_button  {
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    text-align:justify;
    border-style:solid;
}
.my_button:after    {
    content:'X';
    float:right;
    font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<button class="my_button">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</button>
```

You see the big `X` is below the text.

But I'd like to have the `X` vertical aligned on the right side and the text on the left.

Just like this example:
[image: Example]

How can I do that? I tried with `margin`, `padding`, `width` but none of them is working.

Comment: Do you really want this to be a `:before` element? A `background-image` may be more appropriate and simpler to work with.

Comment: This is because I need to programmatically change `content:'X'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @daggett and @dantheman for their help but I ended up with another solution.

Problem is, that `display: flex;` causes many problem if I e.g. have an `<u></u>` in the text. There will be missing spaces as well as huge spaces.

I'm now using this code:

```css
.my_button  {
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    text-align:justify;
    border-style:solid;
    
    background-image:url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAAPUlEQVRIiWNgGFHAqlH2v1Wj7H9S9DDRyjGjFoxaMIQsYIQxSM1AhMCx+seMDAx08AFJYLSoGLVg1IKRCgAjdwuA1z8x5AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:calc(100% - 15px) center;
    background-size: 10px 10px;
    padding-right:40px;
}
```

```html
<button class="my_button">Lorem ipsum <u>dolor</u> sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</button>

<button class="my_button">Lorem ipsum <u>dolor</u> sit amet.</button>
```

This is working perfectly, no matter if the text is very long or rather short or if there's an `<u></u>` inside the text.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using flexbox:

```css
.my_button  {
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    text-align:justify;
    border-style:solid;
    display: flex;
}
.my_button:after    {
    content:'X';
    font-size:30px;
    align-self: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button class="my_button">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</button>


<button class="my_button">Lorem ipsum.</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I missed to mention: I also want to keep the `X` on the right side if the text is shorter, like e.g.: `<button class="my_button">Lorem ipsum</button>`

Comment: @David You can use auto margins for this, I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: If using flex then justify-content: space-between is maybe neater, I've added it to my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Just add display: flex and align-items: center to your button. Display flex changes the flow of the elements to be in line with each other. Then aligning the items center will center your X.

```css
.my_button  {
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    text-align:justify;
    border-style:solid;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.my_button:after    {
    content:'X';
    font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<button class="my_button">Lorem ipsum </button>
```